# How to put whitespace into YML

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

```
variables:
  System.Debug: true
  - group: "TheVariableGroup"
  - name: UseDefaultPool
    value: $[variables.UseDefaultPool]
```

Where is the whitespace supposed to go in this?
I can't work it out.

> `/job.yml@AzurePipelineTemplates (Line: 20, Col: 3): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.`

Comment: What are you actually trying to create? The value of `variables` can't be both an array (of objects) _and_ an object. Maybe it's easier to see as JSON, e.g. https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-to-json.

Comment: @Richard, have you tried the suggestion below? Did it resolve the error "While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key" in your pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve error "While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key", change the variable definition as shown below. You need to use `name` variable specifier for `System.Debug`. See more info about specifying variables from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#specify-variables).

```
variables:
  - name: System.Debug
    value: true
  - group: "TheVariableGroup"
  - name: UseDefaultPool
    value: $[variables.UseDefaultPool]
```